# Where to do Header fields configurations for Push Notification for iOS 13?

Tags: ios, push-notification, apple-push-notifications, ios13, pushwoosh

According to [Apple's APNs docs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/usernotifications/setting_up_a_remote_notification_server/sending_notification_requests_to_apns), as of iOS 13 clients of the http api must send header fields for apns-push-type and apns-priority or the requests will fail.

Sure enough, our users who've udpated to the iOS 13 beta aren't getting silent push notifications that we send through [Pushwoosh](https://go.pushwoosh.com/v2/login)

In my code level (in my Xcode)in did all changes whichever is required.

Now only thing is pending that 2 header has to add in payload. ([Here is the article](https://onesignal.com/blog/ios-13-introduces-4-breaking-changes-to-notifications/))

1. First attribute/parameter to the headers for APNS Payloads: **apns-push-type**

   (**Key**: apns-push-type and **Value**: alert or background)
2. Second attribute/parameter to the headers for APNS Payloads: **apns-priority**

   (**Key**: apns-push-type and **Value**: alert or background)

**Where these 2 header fields with values has to be add ?**

**Either from backend database or PushWhoosh ?**

**Or my code level?**

Can anyone help for this?

Because it says that,

“These headers required when delivering notifications to devices running iOS 13”. Furthermore “if the header is missing on required systems, APNs may delay the delivery of the notification or drop it altogether.”

For more information refer following articles,

[iOS 13 and Xcode 11 Changes That Affect Push Notifications](https://onesignal.com/blog/ios-13-introduces-4-breaking-changes-to-notifications/)

[Sending Notification Requests to APNs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/usernotifications/setting_up_a_remote_notification_server/sending_notification_requests_to_apns?language=objc)

Comment: Typo in your question -> the Key/Value for apns-priority should be apns-priority and 5, according to the WWDC documentation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is information given by **Pushwoosh Team**,

> First of all, it should be emphasised that we took the necessary
>   actions on our side before the release of the iOS 13 to avoid issues
>   with silent pushes.
>
> Regarding the apns-priority parameter, please note that our sender
>   always includes this parameter for iOS silent pushes by default. So it
>   is not necessary to add it by yourself.
>
> As for the apns-push-type parameter, it was introduced with iOS 13. It
>   is required for pushes to watchOS and is not required(for now) for
>   pushes to iOS. This parameter does not add any "tricky" behaviour for
>   push notifications. This is also described in the Apple article you
>   have provided.

Here is the Screenshot of my email,
[image: Sceenshot Of Email]

So, there is no need to do the changes you asked for.

Comment: Does not solve the issue with Silent Pushes with PushWoosh not being delivered..